# why does Linux kernel use do_div instead of /?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

For 64-bit division, what is the difference between using `/` and `do_div`? 
only to improve performance? and is it architecture dependent?

[The source code is here.](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/div64.h#L9)

Comment: A link the occurrence will be useful.

Comment: Maybe `do_div()` behaves "well" when dividing by `0`?

Comment: Presumably one can look at the code inside `do_div` to find out what it's doing.

Comment: see [this](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/div64.h#L9). It clearly states that `do_div` is not the same as `/`. It returns the remainder and sets the quotient in place.

Comment: I know it returns remainder, but you can use % and / pair to do the same. that's not the point.

Comment: The X86 platform provides an instruction that can return the remainder and the quotient in a single instruction. If you perform a % and / pair a compiler might not optimize it.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, if x86 has such instruction, why in do_div it implements the division by some shift ways instead of calling this 'div' instruction via asm? is there any other consideration of this choice?

Comment: @LeslieLi it uses shift only for certain cases, (like poweof2). Because shift is faster than div instruction. In other cases it uses a single instruction. See [here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/div64.h#L35)

Comment: I see, I looked into the wrong codes. so all of my concerns are cleared, thanks a lot to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of this macro and functions in this module is optimization. The comment in the kernel code is pretty clear:

```
/*
 * do_div() is NOT a C function. It wants to return
 * two values (the quotient and the remainder), but
 * since that doesn't work very well in C, what it
 * does is:
 *
 * - modifies the 64-bit dividend _in_place_
 * - returns the 32-bit remainder
 *
 * This ends up being the most efficient "calling
 * convention" on x86.
 */
```

The macro is used in the kernel to compute both the quotient and the remainder in a single step with a single division instead of 2 operations in standard C potentially producing 2 division opcodes.

Indeed Intel x86 CPUs compute both the quotient and the remainder of an integer division with a single instruction. The macro uses inline assembly to take advantage of this, while the C compiler might not optimize 2 separate computations with `/` and `%` into a single opcode.

At the time this code was written, most compilers did not and the division opcode was very costly, so Linus decided to use a special function to optimize this computation.

Note that the C Standard provides a set of functions for this purpose (declared in `<stdlib.h>`):

```
div_t div(int numer, int denom);
ldiv_t ldiv(long int numer, long int denom);
lldiv_t lldiv(long long int numer, long long int denom);
```

The linux kernel targets systems that may not have a standard compliant compiler and definitely predates some of these standard additions, so it has its own versions of these functions as a macro, and some others in the same module.

Comment: OK, seems the most benifit is to get quotient and remainder in one division

Comment: @LeslieLi: yes, exactly.

Comment: @LeslieLi: would you consider accepting this answer?

Comment: I have a further question of it, some architecture has 'div' hardware instruction, why do_div implementation uses shift ways instead of invoking 'div' instruction by a simple asm line?

Comment: @LeslieLi: `do_div` is a macro: it uses the gcc specific extension `__builtin_constant_p` to check if the dividend is a constant and if it is a power of 2, expands to shift and mask operations, much faster than the `div` opcode. Modern compilers do this automatically, but again, the purpose of this macro is to combine the computation of the quotient and remainder in one combined step. It would be less optimal to always expand to a `div` opcode when the dividend is a power of 2. The expansion boils down to a pair of instructions, without branches, everything is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: The interface for the `do_div` macro is quite non-functionlike. Newer code can use the functions defined by `#include <linux/math64.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

The macro is needed because on 32-bit target platforms, writing a "/" will fail to link.

The C library in the kernel is not the one you're using in user space. In user space C programs, the C library will implement the 64-bit division for you, if your CPU does not have a 64-bit divide instruction.

64-bit multiplication is okay, even on 32-bit platforms, but 64-bit divide is a no-no and will get your driver rejected because it won't pass compilation.